# CSP header issues with eval()

Tags: security, laravel-5, vue.js, content-security-policy

I am developing a site, which is still local. I installed [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp) package to add the correct CSP to my site (which I built with Laravel & VueJs).

I have solved them one by one. But now in my chrome console, I don't see any CSP errors anymore. It only shows a blank page. I opened the site in Firefox. There, in the console, I came across the following error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“script-src”). Source: call to eval() or related
>   function blocked by CSP.

I searched the generated bundles for the `eval()` function, but it doesn't appear in any of the files. Does anyone here have some suggestions for me on how to solve this?

Comment: Just an idea, could it be an implicit eval? For example `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` pass their argument to `eval()` if it's a string and not a function reference.

Comment: This is indeed the case. Should I now go on and find out which packages use these statements and add them to the CSP headers?